# How to suppress a dialog from cli?

Tags: ios, macos, cordova

I'm create a nodejs project for build html to ios, i use cordova for background.
The question is that when i run:

`exec('cordova build ios --release --device')`

#### I imported the certificate and provisioningFile already.

That will display a dialog to let me input the OS user's password, but i don't want input it Manually.

I tried this cordova command with cli:
`$ cordova build ios --release --device`

but it still show a dialog.

So, how can i do to suppress this dialog?

Comment: Wasn't --verbose in use for this scope?

Comment: There is no paramter with --verbose - link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-build-command